# glyphicon add margin in JSX

Tags: reactjs, glyphicons

What is the proper way to add the margin to the glyphicon used in React component? 
I tried simple:
`<span className='glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign' margin-left='10px'/>` but it doesn't add the required margin.
According to this:
https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html
what should work I believe is `<span className='glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign' style={margin-left: '10px'}/>` but it gives me error:
`Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ,` I tried also adding the styled-component (which we use over the css) like

```
const glyp = styled.span.attrs({
  className: 'glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign'
)}`
  margin-left: 10px
`
```

but it doesn't render the exclamation mark sign at all (however takes space).

What's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace "`margin-left`" with "`marginLeft`".

From the React docs (which you linked in your question):

> Style keys are camelCased in order to be consistent with accessing the
>   properties on DOM nodes from JS (e.g. node.style.backgroundImage).